# Автоматизация сборки конечного продукта на основе завершенных проектов (Visual Studio/C sharp)

Tags: c#, git, gitlab

Суть вопроса заключается в том: как настроить автоматизацию гит-а так чтоб у конечного продукта были всегда последние версии подключаемых библиотек, то есть что вообще из себя представляет процесс общей сборки.

допустим наш основной проект подключает в себя коллекцию dll, у каждой такой библиотеки свой собственный репозиторий, в которой есть конечная папка Release со всеми необходимыми файлами. Что делаем дальше?

Comment: Настраиваем сервер сборки (build server)? Триггерим сборку по хукам с репозиториев? В своих конфигах указываем только на самые свежие версии зависимостей? Тогда процесс будет такой: кто то пушит в репозиторий -> билд сервер готовит новый билд.

Answer (score 0):

Небходимо использовать *GitLab-Runner* и *Nuget*. Настроить локальный репозиторий Nuget-пакетов. Поднять *GitLab-Runner* на Винде. При пуше библиотек, они создают на *GitLab-Runner* Nuget-пакет и укладывают в репозиторий. При сборке основного проекта делать `nuget restore`.

Про способ с артифактами не рассказываю, он не проще чем с *nuget*. Если использовать только *GitLab-Runner*, то тогда складывать все компилируемые файлы на сетевой диск для общего ипользования.